# CloudSQL - MySql - Memory Leak after Import

Tags: mysql, database, memory-leaks, google-cloud-sql

Using MYSQL second generation on google CloudSQL I am struggling with a memory usage (like a memory leak) after a standard backup import

[image: se]

- The machine is  a db-n1-highmem-2 with 2 CPUs and 13GB of Ram
- The Import has been done using the gcloud import command  from a .gz previously exported using the gcloud export command into a google bucket
- There is just one connection active at that time that is myself with a Mysql workbench tool connected to the instance through a cloudProxy but I am not running anything else
- The behaviour is incremental: if I redo another import from the same file, the usage increases again

[image]

- The storage and the CPU usage are increased during the import and then they behave normally afterwards

This is my configuration
[image]

Restarting the instance, will clear the memory but it will start again after the next import.

Thanks in advance

EDIT Adding a screenshot with a bigger timespan as required (last 4 days)

[image: 4 days span]

CPU Usage over the last 7 days
[image: CUP Usage]

Comment: Could you post the same graph after your last import plus 4 hours for MySQL to have time to complete the import processing, including storing the data to your tables? Are you on a Dedicated or Shared server?

Comment: @WilsonHauck thanks for your comment. I have updated uploaded a screenshot with the last 4 days memory usage ( as you can see at that time the import is done). Also the MySQL servers are hosted on google cloud  in a virtual machine (the production one from the last screenshot is a [db-n1-highmem-4](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types))

Comment: Tonino, Thanks for new screen shot. Additional information request. 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;   as of now, please - avoid stop/start or restart today
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
G) SELECT name, count FROM information_schema.innodb_metrics ORDER BY name; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Thanks @WilsonHauck. Please find below 
Global Status: 

    https://pastebin.com/KUTUyLWA

Global VArs: 

    https://pastebin.com/rTim1Y7s

Process List: (The Host is the cloudSQLProxy IPs used in the connection pool)

    https://pastebin.com/wGrSCBFR 

Engine Status: 

    https://pastebin.com/FVVTJnCH

InnoDB Metrics: 

    https://pastebin.com/y0mtQcgP

Comment: Thank you, analysis in process.  Will try to have completed in 24 hours.

Comment: The additional consumption appears to be consistent before 18:00 every day.  Could you post all prep activities related to the daily import and the import request.  Is this a cron scheduled job? What is the size of the input file(s) according to your OS? Could we have a Skype Talk on your Thursday?  I am in UTC -6 time zone.  Same time as Chicago, IL USA.

Comment: thanks Wilson. However this is more a cloud SQL related issue and if it was something that is normal as per answer below, then I need to find another way. I know that it is part of your company service to offer MySQL consultancy  but it is just me so I can't offer anything for that nor have a skype meeting at that timezone unfortunately. However thanks again :)

Comment: Only 1/2 of our contacts are with people on this side of the world.  Our hours are flexible.  Could you post all prep activities related to the daily import and the import request. Is this a cron scheduled job? What is the size of the input file(s) according to your OS?

Comment: About the scheduled job, no, it is a  manual job done thourgh the google cloud interface to export/import a SQL file  https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/importing and the size of the SQL file  is 150Mb

Comment: And what happens if you keep doing import/export until all RAM is consumed?  Does CloudSQL restart?

Comment: @dancarter sorry for the very late reply. Anyway it does not restart but its CPU goes up to 100% and it gets stuck trying to free the memory. as today, we keep restarting CloudSQL automatically every weekend to clear the memory leak but...

Answer (score 1):

Rate Per Second = RPS

Suggestions to consider for your Google Cloud Database flags,

```
read_rnd_buffer_size=128K  # from 256K to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS of 1,883
read_buffer_size=512K  # from 128K to reduce handler_read_next RPS of 6374
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  # from 2048 to conserve 90% of CPU cycles used for function
thread_cache_size=100  # from 48 for less overhead to support your 169 max_used_connections
```

You should find these dynamic configuration changes will REDUCE CPU busy significantly.

Additional info requested today may reveal why your RAM use goes up every day before 18:00.

Comment: Actually the CPU utilization is not a big deal because it never had spikes more than 20% (I have added a CPU utilization screenshot in my initial Question). The 18 usually it is the time when I do the manual export/import procedure as reported. The same spike happens if I run a mysqldump command to export and import the entire database (structure + data) so the behavior using the gcloud command or a pure mysql command is the same

Answer (score 0):

To me this looks like a normal behavior. Linux always tries to [consume](https://www.linuxatemyram.com/) free memory for buffering.

I don't know how caching algorithms work under the hood, but may be when user imports data MySQL prompts linux to cache it because it might be needed immediately.

Please refer to [this thread](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/62607/large-ram-use-after-import-database-ubuntu-server) for better explanation.